# Need Help starting activity using broadcast reciever

Tags: android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, pubnub

I am working on a  senior project in pubnub android api. The example application works with toasting when a message is received. However,I want to start another activity when a message is received. Basically, It is a home alarm system where the message comes from raspberry pi. Upon receiving the message, a new activity should display where the user can enter a pin code that was used to lock the system to be able to stop the alarm. Everything works as desired only when the application is running. I can't get the new activity to show when the application is not running, even if it receives a message. How can I achieve that? I am starting the alarm activity in a runOnUiThread() then set  startAlarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) as suggested in this post: [Start Activity from a Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386461/start-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver). This does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Google cloud messaging (as a push notification service).

When the event happens in the Raspberry you can send a message to the android device using GCM. The messaging approach is better than creating a periodic task in order to check if there are new messages.

- In order to implement GCM on the android device take a look at this link:
  https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

In the example they create a notification in the notification bar, but you can start a new activity instead of creating a notification. In this link you can find how to start a new activity:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

- On the raspberry side the easiest way for sending the message to the device might be using just curl:

  curl -X POST \ 
  -H "Authorization: key= YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_KEY" \ 
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
  -d '{ 
  "registration_ids": [ 
  "YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN" 
  ], 
  "data": { 
  "message": "YOUR_MESSAGE" 
  } 
  }' \ 
  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send